# Does quartz requires administrator account in order to fire triggers?

Tags: c#, scheduling, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, user-accounts

I have a windows service which uses quartz.net for job scheduling. Service works just fine on my local machine. But when deploy it to the server and run it as network service or any other defined user, the triggers won't fire. When I set the service account as the Administrator it works as expected. Is service account has anything to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Quartz.NET does not need special administrative permissions, but your jobs and other logic might.

You probably should start with getting logging working, [here's a good tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/17/quartz.net-windows-service-configure-logging.aspx). After getting some logging information you probably are closer to the root cause which could be something not related directly to Quartz at all.

Also have try-catches around starting your service and add proper logging.